# Symfony 3 - How to handle JSON request with a form

Tags: php, json, symfony

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to handle a JSON request with Symfony forms (using v3.0.1).

Here is my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/tablet")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function tabletAction(Request $request)
{
    $tablet = new Tablet();
    $form = $this->createForm(ApiTabletType::class, $tablet);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($tablet);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return new Response('');
}
```

And my form:

```
class ApiTabletType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('macAddress')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tablet'
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I send a POST request with the Content-Type header properly set to application/json, my form is invalid... all fields are null.

Here is the exception message I get if I comment the `if ($form->isValid())` line :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tablet
>   (mac_address, site_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, null]:

I've tried sending different JSON with the same result each time:

- `{"id":"9","macAddress":"5E:FF:56:A2:AF:15"}`
- `{"api_tablet":{"id":"9","macAddress":"5E:FF:56:A2:AF:15"}}`

"api_tablet" being what `getBlockPrefix` returns (Symfony 3 equivalent to form types `getName` method in Symfony 2).

Can anyone tell me what I've been doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried overriding getBlockPrefix in my form type. The form fields have no prefix anymore, but still no luck :/

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Render the form and take a look at the element names.  You will quickly see that macAddress element is named something like 'form[macAddress]'  I myself do not use forms for rest stuff.  I think the naming issue is more trouble than it's worth.  But other folks think otherwise.  Might want to take a look at the FOSRestBundle.

Comment: I tried rendering the form, the form is named "api_tablet" and the element "api_tablet_macAddress".
I tried using "api_tablet_macAddress" instead of "macAddress" (with or without the parent node, as mentionned in my question) but no success either.
(I'd like to avoid using FOSRestBundle, since the API I need is really small. I'd rather not add a bundle for such a basic task.)

Comment: You are looking at the id.  The element name is: name="api_tablet[macAddress]".  Setting blockName to '' does make the api_table prefix go away though your form name is now blank as well which is not really desirable.  By the way, javascript sometimes has trouble with [] so use the browser F12 key to verify what is actually being posted.

Comment: You're totally right, my bad. I removed the getBlockPrefix override and tried using brackets in my JSON, but no luck either.

Comment: The thing is that a JSON request (a request were the request body is a JSON string) is not populated the same way as a "regular" HTTP request (you can dump the `Request` object to see the difference). Thus, you need to first "decode" the request body. You can take a look at [the BodyListener from FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/1.7/EventListener/BodyListener.php) for some inspiration (implementing a custom request handler would probably work too, but imho that's not easier).

Comment: Exactly.  Which is why I avoid using Symfony forms and json.

Comment: Several posts I found lead me to think that Symfony was able to handle JSON natively, now I understand why I wasn't able to find any working example.
Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 18):

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
$form->submit($data);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // and so on…
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can drop forms and populate->validate entities

```
$jsonData = $request->getContent();
$serializer->deserialize($jsonData, Entity::class, 'json', [
    'object_to_populate' => $entity,
]);
$violations = $validator->validate($entity);

if (!$violations->count()) {

    return Response('Valid entity');
}

return new Response('Invalid entity');
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-in-an-existing-object

https://symfony.com/components/Validator

Comment: I'm using validator classes in a project as well. Way simpler than using an in-between form.

Comment: This will not work if for example form has extra non mapped fields such as `agreeTerms`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the FOSRestBundle.

Here's an example config I use at the moment:

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
        force_redirects:
          html: true
        formats:
            jsonp: true
            json: true
            xml: false
            rss: false
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        jsonp_handler: ~
    body_listener: true
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    format_listener:
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { path: ^/, priorities: [ 'html', 'json' ], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
    routing_loader:
            default_format: ~
            include_format: true
    exception:
        enabled: true
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
        messages:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': true
```

Make sure you have getBlockPrefix defined with something (I haven't tried empty strings so it might work):

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
   return 'api_tablet'
}
```

Disable CSRF protection for good measure:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'csrf_protection' => false,
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tablet'
    ]);
}
```

You can then POST the following data to the form:

```
{"api_tablet":{"macAddress":"5E:FF:56:A2:AF:15"}}
```

**Notes / caveats:**

- You need to make sure your Form is configured with all the fields of
  the Entity. You can configure what you need in a validator.
- You have to post in camelCase. FOSRestBundle supports Array
  Normalization, which I haven't tried, but apparently that will let
  you post in underscores.