# Issue with POST Request in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, rest, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

**I'm sending Following inputs from postman [POST] to localhost:8000**

```
{
"UserName" : "JohnDoe",
"Password": "JohnDoe123",
"Email": "JohnDoe@email.com",
"FirstName": "John",
"LastName": "Doe"
}
```

**This is the Form : userForm.php**

```
class userForm extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
        ->add('UserName')
        ->add('Password')
        ->add('Email')
        ->add('FirstName')
        ->add('LastName')
    ;
}


public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $optionsResolver) {

    $optionsResolver->setDefaults(
 [

        array(

            'data_class' => user::class,
        )
  ]
    );
    }
 }
```

**Controller: PostController.php**

```
    public function createPostAction(Request $request) {

    $data = $request->getContent();


    $user = $this->get('jms_serializer')
    ->deserialize($data, 'AppBundle\Entity\user' ,'json');
    var_dump($user);
    exit();
    $user = new user();

    $form = $this->createForm(userForm::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

    $errors = $form->getErrors();
    $response = array(
        'message' => 'success',
        'errors' => null,
    );

    return new JsonResponse($response, 200);
}
```

This is what i got in Postman

> object(AppBundle\Entity\user)#2175 (6)
>    {
>    ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\user":private]=>
>    NULL
>    ["userName":"AppBundle\Entity\user":private]=>
>    NULL
>    ["password":"AppBundle\Entity\user":private]=>
>    NULL
>    ["email":"AppBundle\Entity\user":private]=>
>    NULL
>    ["firstName":"AppBundle\Entity\user":private]=>
>    NULL
>    ["lastName":"AppBundle\Entity\user":private]=>
>    NULL
>    }

Since I'm new to this and I don't know what to do.

Comment: It's because you are sending a JSON in body, but POST requests work in a slightly different way. You will have to search and read on your own, because it would be A LOT to write in an answer here.

Comment: The form component actually expects element names to be form[Username], form[Password] etc.  Just one of those fun quirks.  And yes json can be an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619020/symfony-3-how-to-handle-json-request-with-a-form

Comment: @AlexKarshin, i tried sending from angular Form but no luck...

Comment: try to dump the data right after `$data = $request->getContent();` to see what is returned with the method `dump($data)`. Also i don't know if its normal but postman displays userName, password, etc... with a tiny letter first instead of displaying something such as UserName, Password, an so on.

Comment: Same issue. It seems form is not catching the value.